# Mongo and find always limited to 100 with geo data

Tags: mongodb, find

While trying to experiment with mongo performance I found strange behaviour of my mongo db.

First of all i filled it with the following query:

```
for (i=0; i < 10000000; i++){db.location.insert( {_id: Math.floor((Math.random()*10000000000)+1), position: [Math.round(Math.random()*10000)/10000, Math.round(Math.random()*10000)/10000]} )}
```

next:

```
db.location.ensureIndex( {position: "2d"} )
```

Then i execute query:

```
db.location.find( {position: { $near: [1,1], $maxDistance: 1/111.12  } } )
```

Whatever i try to do i get always size or count result 100.

I noticed in documentation that defualt limit is 100. I tried also to override it with bigger than 100 values. Unfortunately I failed.

Have you ever encountered such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all document query like

```
cordinate = [1,1];
maxDistance = 1/111.12 ;

db.location.find({"position" : {"$within" : 
                                      {"$center" : [cordinate , maxDistance ]}
                                }
                  });
```

Comment: your solution seems to work. Thank you. Could you give me a tip how it is different than from previous approach? does "within" bring important difference?

Answer (score 1):

From oficial [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/):

> The $near operator requires a geospatial index: a 2dsphere index for GeoJSON points; a 2d index for legacy coordinate pairs. By default, queries that use a 2d index return a limit of 100 documents; **however you may use [limit()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) to change the number of results**.

And also look at 'Note' in the and of this tutorial page.

**Update:**
As Sumeet wrote in comment to his answer - it is open issue.
For be sure, that your query return correct count, that you specifying in limit method, you could try to use `.limit(<some_number>).explain().n` with your cursor, if you working in the shell.

Comment: This is exacly what I found previously. I limited and rechecked it. Find returns more values but count or size still show 100

Comment: `count` have parameter `applySkipLimit`, you could write `.count(true)` for apply skip and limit influence (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/). But I've tried it now with `$near` and it is not working. Now I researching what is happens.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the same scenario on my MongoDB and it works fine. I gave limit of 145 and it gave me 145 records. However as mentioned in the documentation it give me 100 records if I do not specify any limit.

```
db.location.find( {position: { $near: [1,1], $maxDistance: 1  } } ).limit(145)
```

I tried using above statement.
Please note that I changed the value of $maxDistance so that I get lot of records.

Comment: You are right. I calculated it without count/size. But count/size still shows 100 as sum of found documents: db.location.find( {position: { $near: [1,1], $maxDistance: 1  } } ).limit(145).count()

Comment: and what if I do not  want any limits? limit(0) does not work

Comment: limit(0) is equivalent to not specifying the limit itself.

Comment: @Lormitto: Yes it seems like the count() show the wrong result. However if you try calling explain() function on this query you can see that it returns 145 documents when limit(145) is used.