# Parse.com geospatial Count query always limited to 100

Tags: parse-platform

My goal is to retrieve a count that can be used to show an estimate of the number of devices that would receive a push based on the same criteria.  However, I believe that I am running up against a bug in MongoDB that I have found workarounds for but I am looking for a similar workaround using Parse.

This link provides a description of the issue and a possible workaround: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongomapper/MfRDh2vtCFg

Also this stackoverflow: [Mongo and find always limited to 100 with geo data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207223/mongo-and-find-always-limited-to-100-with-geo-data)

I just can't figure out how to get the workaround to work with Parse.  Parse's documentation for the REST API Geo Queries shows an example using $within but it seems like the only valid query for $within is a $box query.  I tried to use $center, $centerSphere, etc but Parse just returned an error that it expected the key "$box".

I am using the Parse REST API.  The query looks like the following with some formatting that makes it readable:

```
installations/?where={
    "channels": {
        "$in": ["Everyone"],
        "$nin": []
    },
    "location": {
        "$nearSphere": {
            "__type": "GeoPoint",
            "latitude": 35.4432,
            "longitude": -97.6238
        },
        "$maxDistanceInMiles": 10
    }
}
&count=1
&limit=0
```

My questions:
Is there a way to get the suggested workarounds working in Parse?  Maybe something that is undocumented?  If not using the REST API maybe the .NET SDK?

Comment: Since this is just for the purpose of being an estimate to the user for now we will use the $within $box query.  However, it is still unfortunate that MongoDB provides a $within $center query option but Parse's API  blocks using that option for some reason.  http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/operator/query/center/ pointing to the older version documentation since it seems to match up better with Parse's implementation of it (within instead of geoWithin, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a nice workaround for this issue to date. I'd look at doing this in cloud code where you can make a number of separate count requests recursively and then return the result without the network overhead for each request.

Create your cloud function and the query to run with all the associated criteria, then use a function like:

```
function recursiveCountForQuery(query, count) {
    console.log("recursiveCountForQuery now @ " + count);

    query.limit(100);
    query.skip(count);

    return query.find().then(function(values) {
        var number = values.length;
        var total = count + number;

        if (number < 100 || total >= 500) {
            return Parse.Promise.as(total);
        } else {
            return recursiveCountForQuery(query, total);
        }
    });
}
```

to run the query and wait for the promise to return the count (the `total >= 500` is so it doesn't run too long but can be removed / changed depending on your use case).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I forgot that I had actually looked into the possibility of using cloud code for this and apologize that I forgot to mention that in my original post.  I think normally this would be a good work around.  However, without the ability to share cloud code between Apps this turns into an exponential deployment and maintenance headache for our particular situation at the moment.  We actually moved away from Parse for everything except Push notifications for this reason, it just didn't fit our model.