# Why mongodb not giving me more than 100 documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Why does my query not working with more than 100 documents in collection?

```
db.collection('allowedmacs').find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
console.log(docs);
}
```

err says this:

```
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'connection destroyed, not possible to instantiate cursor'
```

If documents <100 all works fine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're probably doing something like this:

```
db.collection('allowedmacs').find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
  console.log(docs);
});
db.close();
```

So you're closing the database before the callback to `toArray` has been called (although it *may* work on some occassions).

Instead, try this:

```
db.collection('allowedmacs').find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
  console.log(docs);
  db.close();
});
```

Answer (score -3):

in [source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/) there is written:

> MongoDB supports no more than 100 levels of nesting for BSON documents.

maybe you look into : [Mongo and find always limited to 100 with geo data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207223/mongo-and-find-always-limited-to-100-with-geo-data)